# how to Multiple textarea data combined JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function doConcat()
{
    document.releaseNotes.releaseNoteCombined.value = "\n"+ document.releaseNotes.who.value +"\n\n\n"+ document.releaseNotes.problem.value +"\n\n\n"+ document.releaseNotes.specs.value ;
}
```

```css
body { background:black;
        }
```

```html
<form name="releaseNotes">
<br>
<textarea name="who" cols="40" rows="5">123
</textarea>
  <br>
<textarea name="problem" cols="40" rows="5">text1 text2 text3
</textarea>
  <br>
<textarea name="specs" cols="40" rows="5">red1 red2 red3
</textarea>
  <br>


<br>
<input type="button" align="middle" onclick="doConcat()" value="Generate" style="height: 50px; width: 120px" />
<br>
  
<textarea name="releaseNoteCombined" cols="40" rows="25">
</textarea><br>
</form>
```

how to Multiple textarea data combined، So that it sorts the data lines،Then data combined it's

Thus the column .

1

text1

red1

2

text2

red2

3

text3

red3

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you just want to *interleave* the data.

We'll split the textarea's values into arrays then combine them index by index (group the index 0 items from each array, then index 1, etc.).

```js
function doConcat() {
  var whoValues = document.releaseNotes.who.value.trim().split(""); // no space here
  var problemValues = document.releaseNotes.problem.value.trim().split(" ");
  var specsValues = document.releaseNotes.specs.value.trim().split(" ");

  const maxLength = Math.max(whoValues.length, problemValues.length, specsValues.length);
  var result = "\n";

  for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    if (i < whoValues.length) {
      result += whoValues[i] + "\n";
    }
    if (i < problemValues.length) {
      result += problemValues[i] + "\n";
    }
    if (i < specsValues.length) {
      result += specsValues[i] + "\n";
    }
    result += "\n";
  }

  document.releaseNotes.releaseNoteCombined.value = result;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<form name="releaseNotes">
  <br>
  <textarea name="who" cols="40" rows="5">123
</textarea>
  <br>
  <textarea name="problem" cols="40" rows="5">text1 text2 text3
</textarea>
  <br>
  <textarea name="specs" cols="40" rows="5">red1 red2 red3
</textarea>
  <br>

  <br>
  <input type="button" align="middle" onclick="doConcat()" value="Generate" style="height: 50px; width: 120px" />
  <br>

  <textarea name="releaseNoteCombined" cols="40" rows="25">
</textarea><br>
</form>
```